# Hibernate char discriminator value

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

Why does hibernate think that char discriminators are not safe?

```
Using default @DiscriminatorValue for a discriminator of type CHAR is not safe
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably because the CHAR type consists in appending spaces to every value until the resulting text has the length of the column. This leads to all sorts of nasty bugs that don't occur with varchars.

Answer (score 3):

Is is there an abstract ancestor in your inheritance tree?

When you have an abstract base class marked as an @Entity, Hibernate appears to think the abstract class should have a discriminator value even though there will never be a database row for that type. [There is a Hibernate bug for this issue.](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5798)

One workaround might be to use @MappedSuperclass. The downside: you wouldn't be able to do queries based on the abstract type, as it would no longer be an @Entity.

You may wish to re-evaluate whether inheritance is actually a good fit for your entity model. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667703/jpa-implementing-model-hiearchy-mappedsuperclass-vs-inheritence).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the default discriminator value for `CHAR` is just spaces, which can probably lead to a variety of misunderstandings.

I ran into this error message when I had a concrete base class that was not annotated with a `@DiscriminatorValue`.  The error resolved when I added the annotation.

Make sure that every concrete class in your mapped type hierarchy has a `@DiscriminatorValue`, including the base class, and this error might go away.