# Is there a configurable alternative to using @Version?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm placing an annotated field with `@Version` on it in all my JPA domain classes, however this just seems like additional boiler plate.  Is there a way to get around this perhaps via configuration?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the JPA specification tells us you can't change the `@Version` annotation via "configuration". You either use `@Version` in your program code or you don't.

Referring to the official [JPA specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) (final version, JPA 2.1) in Section 3.4.2 (page 90) we find:

> An entity is automatically enabled for optimistic locking *if* it has a property or field mapped with a `Version` mapping.
>
> [...]
>
> If only some entities contain version attributes, the persistence provider runtime is required to check those entities for which version attributes have been specified. The *consistency* of the object graph *is not guaranteed*, but the absence of version attributes on some of the entities will not stop operations from completing.

However, you can use the concept of *inheritance* to provide the `@Version`only in one spot via an *abstract* base class. This class you be written as follows:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractBaseEntity { 

    public static final long INVALID_OBJECT_ID = -42;

    @Version
    private int version;    

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequence-object", sequenceName = "ID_MASTER_SEQ")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequence-object")
    @Column(name = "id")
    protected Long objectID = INVALID_OBJECT_ID;

    public final int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    @Override
    public long getObjectID() {
        return objectID;
    }

    // ... maybe other methods or fields ...
}
```

Thus, all your `@Entity` annotated sub-classes that inherit from `AbstractPersistentEntity` are provided with both properties: (i) `objectID`and (ii) `version` at once. For instance, class `SomeClass` can be written as:

```
@Entity
public class SomeClass extends AbstractBaseEntity /*implements SomeInterface*/ {
    // ... specific methods or fields ...
}
```

For details on the use of `@MappedSuperclass` see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36513791/2849346).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Awesome - thanks - I'm using Spring's AbstractPersitable ATM, so I'll probably just subclass that, unless you know of something within Spring that also provides the version property.