# detached entity passed to persist: model.Company

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

I'm getting the detached entity passed to persist: model. Company when I use @OneToMany mapping. I tried different method but the same result.
I added @OneToMany with CascadeTypes Persist and all. Remove those. 
Set the manager and tried to persist, commented the set of manager and tried to persist. None of them worked.

**Company:**

```
@Entity
public class Company {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private int age;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<Manager> managers;

    private String name;


    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setManagers(Set<Manager> managers) {
        this.managers = managers;
    }


    public Set<Manager> getManager() {
        return managers;
    }

}
```

**Manager**

```
@Entity
public class Manager {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Test**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpatestproject");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

    //  Manager m1 = new Manager();
    //  m1.setName("abc");
    //  Manager m2 = new Manager();
    //  m2.setName("def");
    //  Set<Manager> managers = new HashSet();
    //  managers.add(m1);
    //  managers.add(m2);
    //  

        Company company = new Company();
        company.setId(1);
        company.setName("LTE");
    //  company.setManagers(managers);


        tx.begin();

        em.persist(company);
        tx.commit();
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting the Company id manually with `company.setId(1);`.

A `@GeneratedValue` is best left alone.

The persistence context will assume the record already exists but is *detached* since the id is set but the entity is not in the current persistence context (represented by the current EntityManager).

Answer (score 0):

First, one can use an abstract base class annotated with [`@MappedSuperClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36513791/2849346) for generic aspects, such as primary key management:

```
@MappedSuperClass
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "pk-sequence")
    //@SequenceGenerator(name = "pk-sequence", sequenceName = "ID_GEN", allocationSize = 1)
    protected Long objectID = -1;

    @Version
    private int version;

    public int getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public long getObjectID() {
        return objectID;
    }   
}
```

Note: there is no setter for either the `objectID` nor for the `version` attribute. Thus, at runtime, both values will *remain under control* by the ORM **only**. This way, instances of `EntityManager` can safely manage the [lifecycle of an `Entity`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30168342/2849346). See another answer for details on [`@Version`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411240/2849346). Moreover, this generic approach can be enhanced to include other generic aspects, e.g. creation/modification date/timestamps.

This will greatly simplify your existing `@Entity` classes.

```
@Entity
public class Company extends AbstractEntity  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int age;

    // @ElementCollection <-- Use a 1-n annotation here instead.
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
    // to ensure non persisted manager objects will be persisted via a cascade chain here...
    private Set<Manager> managers;

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setManagers(Set<Manager> managers) {
        this.managers = managers;
    }


    public Set<Manager> getManager() {
        return managers;
    }

}
```

Please also note that I commented out `@ElementCollection` but instead changed the mapping to make use of the `@OneToMany` annotation. The rationale behind this is that an `ElementCollection` can only be used to specify [a one-to-many relationship to an `Embeddable` object, or basic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html) (e.g., referenced via a Set< Integer >, etc.) which is not the case for the entity class `Manager`.

Finally,

```
@Entity
public class Manager extends AbstractEntity {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

With the above changes you should be able to run the code presented in `Test#main(..)` method. Please note, that you should still check the correct association order before persisting. I have not tested the provided code snippet as presented in your question; nevertheless you should be able to make it work.

Hope it helps.