# Reusing entities in JPA/Spring Boot

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-boot

I have an existing entity **that cannot be modified** as below:

```
@Entity
public class ChildEntity implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Column(name="id")
private String id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
//getters, setters, et al.
```

I have a new query that returns the same data as above *with an extra column* as below:

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Column(name="extra")
private String extra;
@Id
@Column(name="id")
private String id;
@Column(name="name")
private String name;
//getters, setters, et al. from child
```

As visible above, I want to reduce the above class to something like this:

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Column(name="extra")
private String extra;
@Embedded
private ChildEntity entity; //ChildEntity will have annotation @Embeddable
//getters, setters, of extra param
```

But when I run the native query that assigns data to a list of `ParentEntity`, it does not recognize `ChildEntity`.

My queries would be something like this:

```
ChildEntity: select name,id from table where (/*some condition*/)
ParentEntity: select extra,name,id from table where (/*some condition*/)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: try to add the whole query creation along with assignement

Comment: `Entity`s cannot be `Embeddable`, it's either or.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [37.1.6 Embeddable Classes in Entities](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm#BNBQA)

> Embeddable classes are used to represent the state of an entity but
>   don't have a persistent identity of their own, unlike entity classes.

Looking back at your entities, you might either need `@MappedSuperclass` or `@Inheritance` depending on your model associations. This thread [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667703/jpa-implementing-model-hierarchy-mappedsuperclass-vs-inheritance) the point clearly.