# Hibernate - How to avoid duplicates across multiple tables in database

Tags: hibernate, jpa, duplicates

Let's assume I have an entity called `Employee`, which contains 10 columns. I have some other entites like `Manager`, `Salesman`, `Lawyer` and `HumanResource`. All these classes will inherit from `Employee` and gonna have one or two different fields of their own. What I want to do is avoid all the duplicate values saved in the database. If I use `@MappedSuperclass`, all fields will be saved into all tables and therefore duplicates. If I use `@Embedded`, the result will be the same. I wonder what other options do I have, beside creating `Employee` entity/table with `@OneToMany` relationship with the other entites?

Comment: `@MappedSuperclass` is only for handling cases where there is inheritance in the Java domain model and not in the database. For inheritance in the model **and** in the database see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667703/jpa-implementing-model-hierarchy-mappedsuperclass-vs-inheritance

Comment: @AlanHay I have a quick question regarding `@Interitance`. Is a `@NamedQuery` defined in the superclass accessible from child classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)` to have all 10 fields from Employee base class in single *Employee* table.

```java
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Entity
public  abstract class Employee {...}

@Entity
public class Manager{
}
```

In case of using `InheritanceType.JOINED` additional table will be created for each `@Entity` subclass.

Read about different Inheritance Strategies (Single Table, Joined table, Table per class) here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jpa/jpa_advanced_mappings.htm